# getting broken image icon when trying to align text with image in react application

Tags: html, reactjs, image, bootstrap-4

I am building a simple React app and I am having trouble trying to align some text with an image.  At the moment it shows a broken icon and I am wondering if I have the correct path to the image.  Below is an image of my file structure.[image]

The image I am trying to show is back-stroke2.jpg.  I can see the image in the code editor so I don't think the problem is with the image.  Below I have listed the code I have in the Contact.jsx

```
 <div className="container">

           <img className="vertical-align:right" src="../images/back- 
           stroke2.jpg" alt="swimmer"></img>  
           <span className="">Works.</span>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import the image file to your component. Try this:

```
import myImageSource from '../images/back-stroke2.jpg'

...

render() (
    <img src={myImageSource} />
)
```

Comment: Thanks that was great J.Lindebro.  Now I need to figure out on how to reduce the image as it looks massive.